# Kruskal's algorithm explanation

Tags: c++, algorithm, greedy, kruskals-algorithm

I was reading wikipeida and found Kruskal's Pseudocode as the following:

```
KRUSKAL(G):    
    foreach v ∈ G.V:    
        MAKE_SET(v)    
    G.E = sort(G.E)    
    i = 0    
    while (i != |V|-1):      
        pick the next (u, v) edge from sorted list of edges G.E        
        if (FIND_SET(u) != FIND_SET(v)):          
            UNION(u, v)        
            i = i + 1
```

I'm not quiet sure what `FIND_SET()` does, and Wikipedia has the follow description:

> if that edge connects two different trees, then add it to the forest, combining two trees into a single tree.

So I guess it checks if two different trees are connected, but what does this really mean?

Comment: “off topic” … how is that off topic?! (@ Close-voter)

Comment: You're misrepresenting the code. Look again at where the `i = i + 1` should go.

Comment: I think the code would be more readily clear if they replaced `if (FIND_SET(u) != FIND_SET(v))` with `if (!inSameSet(u, v))`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Initially, each vertex is in a set all by itself: There is a singleton set `{v}` for every vertex `v`. In the pseudo-code, these sets are the result of `make_set(v)`.

For a given vertex `v`, the function `find_set(v)` gives you the set containing `v`.

The algorithm merges sets iteratively, so if `{u}`, `{v}` are singleton sets initially and there is an edge `(u, v)`, then the algorithm replaces the two sets by their union `{u, v}`. Now both `find_set(u)` and `find_set(v)` will return that set.

The algorithm terminates after you've added `|V| - 1` non-trivial edges, which is precisely the number of edges in a tree.

Answer (score 1):

The `find_set()` is a common operation of a kind of data structure known as Union-Find. The idea of this data structure is to have disjoint sets (of vertex in your example).

In this algorithm I think that each set represents vertex that are connected.

So when you call `find_set()` passing a vertex, you will receive the element that represents that set of connected verxtex.

Answer (score 0):

FIND_SET(x) finds the set associated with edge x, so that the comparison:

```
FIND_SET(u) != FIND_SET(v)
```

Ensures that u and v are not connected to the same thing.  A useful way of thinking about it is that it finds the "values" of u and v where the values are in themselves sets.

The part about merging the forests has nothing to do with FIND_SET, but rather the next line:

```
UNION(u,v)
```

Which merges the two sets.

Answer (score 0):

```
find_set(u)!=find_set(v)
```

signifies the basic property of spanning tree that is it does not make cycles.If they are equal then it shows there is a cycle in graph.

We basically make a forest (of minimum edge weights) through Kruskal algorithm and at each step checks whether it is making cycle or not.

Hope it helps :)